# Can I convert fields in XML to tags using xmlstarlet?

Tags: text-processing, xml, xmlstarlet

I want to convert fields in Tags to tags within that tag for example

```xml
<book name="Data Structure" price="250" pages="350"/>
```

to

```xml
<book name="Data Structure"> 
<price>250</price>
<pages>350</pages>
</book>
```

I want to perform this operation in Linux command line using `xmlstarlet` or `sed` .

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for using [XSLT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt) in conjunction with the `xmlstarlet` command, but that would mean you're probably better off asking this as an `xml`-related question on StackOverflow *assuming if you need help writing the XSLT file itself*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`process.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="//book">
    <xsl:element name="book">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book/@*">
      <xsl:if test="name() = 'name'">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="name() != 'name'">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`input.xml`:

```
<book name="Data Structure" price="250" pages="350"/>
```

#### Command:

`xsltproc process.xsl input.xml`

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book name="Data Structure">
  <price>250</price>
  <pages>350</pages>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that the question says "using `xmlstarlet` or `sed`", but either of those tools would require an awkward amount of typing (and using `sed` to modify *any* structured document format is not advised).  There are other XML-capable tools out there that can do the job a bit less verbosely.

Assuming an XML document like

```xml
<root>
<book name="Data Structure 1" price="250" pages="350"/>
<book name="Data Structure 2" price="350" pages="250"/>
<book name="Data Structure 3" price="450" pages="150"/>
</root>
```

Then you may use `xq` (part of `yq`, a YAML parser wrapper around `jq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to do what it is you want to do, using a `jq` expression.

The `xq` tool parses the example XML document into an equivalent JSON document:

```json
{
  "root": {
    "book": [
      {
        "@name": "Data Structure 1",
        "@price": "250",
        "@pages": "350"
      },
      {
        "@name": "Data Structure 2",
        "@price": "350",
        "@pages": "250"
      },
      {
        "@name": "Data Structure 3",
        "@price": "450",
        "@pages": "150"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Applying the following expression iterates over the `.root.book[]` array, modifying the keys of each JSON element by removing the initial `@` from the keys that ares not `@name`.  A key with an initial `@` in its name corresponds to an attribute in the XML, so removing the `@` would turn the key into an XML node rather than an attribute of a node.

```bsh
xq -x '.root.book[] |= (with_entries(select(.key != "@name").key |= ltrimstr("@")))' file.xml
```

With my own example file above, this produces

```xml
<root>
  <book name="Data Structure 1">
    <price>250</price>
    <pages>350</pages>
  </book>
  <book name="Data Structure 2">
    <price>350</price>
    <pages>250</pages>
  </book>
  <book name="Data Structure 3">
    <price>450</price>
    <pages>150</pages>
  </book>
</root>
```

---

If your XML document is literally the single node

```xml
<book name="Data Structure" price="250" pages="350"/>
```

then use

```
xq -x '.book |= (with_entries(select(.key != "@name").key|=ltrimstr("@")))' file.xml
```

This is the same expression as above, but applied to just the top-level `.book` section rather than to the elements of a `.root.book[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

Please - don't use `sed` - it's not a suitable tool for the job.

I'd use perl myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' );
$twig->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' );

foreach my $thing ( $twig -> root -> children ) {

    my $newthing = $twig -> root -> insert_new_elt($thing->tag);
    foreach my $key ( keys %{$thing -> atts()} ) {
        $newthing -> insert_new_elt($key, $thing -> att($key));
    }
    $thing -> delete;
}

$twig->print;
```

Outputs:

```
<root>
  <book>
    <pages>350</pages>
    <name>Data Structure</name>
    <price>250</price>
  </book>
</root>
```

That's pretty simple, because we're working with an (anonymous) hash `att()`. To pick out one attribute we have to do a bit more - we need to define that we want to *keep* `name` and insert that as an attribute of our parent element.

This uses `map` which can be a bit of a headache:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::Twig;

my %keep_att = ( name => 1 );
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' );
$twig->parse( \*DATA );

foreach my $thing ( $twig->root->children ) {
    my $newthing = $twig->root->insert_new_elt( $thing->tag,
        { map { $_ => $thing->att($_) } keys %keep_att } );

    foreach my $key ( keys %{ $thing->atts() } ) {
        next if $keep_att{$key};
        $newthing->insert_new_elt( $key, $thing->att($key) );
    }
    $thing->delete;
}

$twig->print;

__DATA__
<root>
<book name="Data Structure" price="250" pages="350"/>
</root>
```

This produces:

```
<root>
  <book name="Data Structure">
    <price>250</price>
    <pages>350</pages>
  </book>
</root>
```

Now, what's going on with that `map` is we're basically splitting out the attributes we want to keep - and re-inserting them into our new element - and the elements we *don't* want to keep, and turning them into children.

A bit like this:

```
foreach my $thing ( $twig->root->children ) {

    my %attributes = %{$thing->atts()};
    my %new_children; 
    foreach my $attr ( keys %attributes ) {
       if ( $keep_att{$attr} ) { 
           #leave it in %attributes; 
       }
       else {
           $new_children{$attr} = $attributes{$attr}; 
           delete $attributes{$attr}
       }
    }
    print Dumper \%attributes;
    print Dumper \%new_children;

    my $newthing = $twig->root->insert_new_elt( $thing->tag,
        { %attributes } );

    foreach my $key ( keys %new_children ) {
        $newthing->insert_new_elt( $key, $new_children{$key} );
    }
    $thing->delete;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to perform this operation in Linux command line using `xmlstarlet` or `sed`

Using `xmlstarlet` 1.6.1 and your input XML file the following command
will produce the output you're after:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --var T 'book' \
 -s '$T' -t elem -n 'price'  -u '$prev' -x 'string(../@price)'  -d '$T/@price' \
 -s '$T' -t elem -n 'pages'  -u '$prev' -x 'string(../@pages)'  -d '$T/@pages' \
file.xml
```

where

- the `T` variable contains the nodeset of `book` elements to convert;
  with a single element in the input file `book` (or `*`) will do,
  if input has `book`s enclosed in a root element, instead `*/book`;
  `//book` selects all, `(//book)[1]` the first
- `-s` / `--subnode` creates an element (`-t elem`) subnode named
  (`-n`) as an attribute for each element in `$T`
- `-u` / `--update` inserts values in each newly created element
  (`$prev`) using a relative XPath expression (`-x`)
- `-d` / `--delete` deletes the attribute in each element in `$T` after
  conversion

`xmlstarlet edit` code can use the convenience `$prev` (aka
`$xstar:prev`) node to refer to the node created by the most recent
`-i` / `--insert`, `-a` / `--append`, or `-s` / `--subnode` option.
Examples of `$prev` are given in
[doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt) and
the source code's
[examples/ed-backref*](https://fossies.org/linux/www/xmlstarlet-1.6.1.tar.gz/).

---

To list attribute names (other than `name`) for all `book`s eliminating
duplicates, e.g. for a script generator, you could say,

```sh
xmlstarlet select -t \
  -m '//book/@*[name() != "name"]' -v 'name()' -n \
file.xml | 
awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

or, using no tools but an `xmlstarlet` supporting the EXSLT
[dyn:map](https://exslt.github.io/dyn/functions/map/index.html)
function:

```sh
xmlstarlet select -t \
  --var T='//book/@*[name() != "name"]' \
  -m 'set:distinct(dyn:map($T,"name()"))' -v . -n \
file.xml
```